# What is the wisdom behind weed being considered haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Cannabis, marijuana, weed, bud whatever you call it is considered haram, by many, due to the fact it is seen as an intoxicant. However, I read an article that shows some benefits compared to risks https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/320984#What-are-the-health-risks-of-marijuana? and it seems like the positives outweight the negatives by a significant mark. It may be considered an intoxicant however it is nowhere near as bad as alcohol. Actually I am trying to find a single documented death by marijuana or even any severe cases and it is pretty hard. Someting that confused me more is on the question is marijuana haram a user stated why is caffeine halal. I checked this and it turns out to be true but caffeine has killed people and although it isnt like hundreds of thousands or something it is still a considerablke amount. If I am correct anything that is harmful in large amounts isnt allowed in small amounts or somethibng along the lines of this. Caffeine can also give you a buzz too.

What is the wisdom behind marijuana being haram? Why is it considered haram and substances that are more dangerous than it arent?

Answer (score -1):

> "That which is intoxicating in large amounts is Haram even if taken in only small amounts"
>
> ~Unknown Source [Hadith?][C]

These drugs are not good for you because they may cause serious  addiction ( may Allah SWT protect us from it ).

Comment: Each hadith report should have a source and authentification and this one is known and certainly quoted in one of the 9 most quoted sunni hadith sources I'd even assume it is in Sunan ibn Majah please search for the hadith in a hadith resource site like sunnah.com or elsewhere and add and share a link reference. Further mark your quotes as such.

Comment: I have no idea how to mark a quote

Comment: Please add references that the addiction is a reason for the drugs being haram.

Comment: @Medi1SaifMedi1Sif  £ I never said that drugs are Haram because of addiction. I said that drugs are NOT GOOD FOR YOU BECAUSE THEY CAUSE ADDICTION!

Comment: @TheMadHatter you've addressed the wrong user.

Comment: @TheMadHatter I am not talking about all drugs although weed may cause some sort of addiction it is not serious and there arent major sideeffects/harms to using it anyway.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Sorry about that